# C# WCF cant see app.config

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration

Ok so here is my scenario.

I have made a WCF Library project. Configured my app.config file. I then created a new console application. Added my WCF Library project to the console app. Then I copied the config file over to my server console app. However, when I run the console application it throws an exception and essentially states that it cant see the app.config file. However, the app.config is clearly inside of the server console application. I can add my endpoints programmatically and make the service work. However, that is not my intention. Is there some sort of trick in order to get the ServiceHost to use the app.config, or more importantly the project to see the app.config?

My app.config

```
<configuration>

<configSections>
</configSections>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
   <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="Services">
     <endpoint address="CompanyService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="NetTcpBinding" contract="Services.ICompany" />
    <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8732/Services/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

My Host Service code:

```
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Company))) {
    host.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate the host service");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It then throws this exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Service 'Services.Company' has     zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might
be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no
service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration fi
le, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element.
```

Comment: ***because no
service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration***

Comment: The error says it's looking for a service named `Services.Company` while your config seems to have it attributed with `name="Services"` Try changing that.

Comment: Thank you Joachim that was the problem. I fixed that and all worked well. I looked at that liked 50 times and wasnt putting 2x2 together.

Comment: Joachim can you please post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @meanbunny if Joachim doesn't post feel free to post the answer yourself and accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

What are you naming the app.config file when you copy it over to the console app? There are specific rules that will need to be followed.

If the console app has an executable name of, e.g. "consoleapp.exe", then the app.config will have to have the name "consoleapp.exe.config"

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that you have called the file app.config, and not yourprogramname.exe.config?

Answer (score 0):

@Jaochim The error says it's looking for a service named Services.Company while your config seems to have it attributed with name="Services" Try changing that.